# Symfony - Acces only to their own customers

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I have these entities

```
User

(ManyToMany)

Customer (OneToOne --> a customer can have a related customer)
```

My app works. Now I want to manage permissions.
When a user is logged in, I want to show only customers related to him and customers related to children customers.

For example,

- Each time I use findAll(), it will find its customers.
- Route /user/4/customer/7 : if customer 7 is not related to user, permission denied

I think I have to override Doctrine Repository or use EntityManagerDecorator
I'm just asking for what is the best practice to figure it ?
Thanks !

Comment: Read this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know voters. I will use it in complement for my project but it won't make what I need in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a better way.

Doctrine Filters

Listenning request on kernel, if my entity is concerned, apply my filter (adding WHERE id= xx)

I use this :
http://blog.michaelperrin.fr/2014/12/05/doctrine-filters/

Answer (score 1):

Basically, operation like searching a specific data should be delegated to the repository. Eventually if you have to search through different data source you could create a service for this specific responibility and inject there needed dependencies. In your case I would say you don't need to ovveride anything just create a UserRepository and write there a function which do what you need.

Check this out:
https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/doctrine/repository.html

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create your own custom findAll() function in your `customerRepository` That filters with your user ?

Something like

```
public function findAllRelatedToUser(User $user)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->innerJoin('c.user', 'u')
                    ->andWhere('u.id = :user_id')
                    ->setParameter('user_id', $user->getId())
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Hello, yes, it is a good idea, but it's an old project and I have many repositories and many findAll, findBy etc in many controllers. But I think I will do like you say